# CLIPS i would like to group my slots together before asserting a new fact using implod$

Tags: implode, clips

Hi i have written a program that will simulate the the propositional laws by making use of explode$ to split all my symbols into different slots. I would now like to combine these together again before asserting the fact.

I have tried using the implode but am not quite sure where to put it.

```
(deftemplate sentence (multislot sent))

(defrule read-from-user
 =>
(printout t "Please enter a sentence: Use ~ for not and => for implies, or(v) and and(^) please " crlf)
(bind ?response (explode$ (readline)))
(bind ?response (replace-member$ ?response "(" (sym-cat "(")))
(bind ?response (replace-member$ ?response ")" (sym-cat ")")))
(bind ?response (replace-member$ ?response "~" (sym-cat "~")))
(bind ?response (replace-member$ ?response "v" (sym-cat "v")))
(bind ?response (replace-member$ ?response "=>" (sym-cat "=>")))
(bind ?response (replace-member$ ?response "^" (sym-cat "^")))
(bind ?response (replace-member$ ?response "v" (sym-cat "v")))
(assert (sentence (sent ?response))))

(defrule or-to-implies
(sentence (sent $?before "(" ?symbolone "v" ?symboltwo ")" $?after))
 =>
(assert (sentence (sent $?before "(" "~" ?symbolone "=>" ?symboltwo ")" $?after))))
```

This is my current output when i enter (PVQ)

```
Please enter a sentence: Use ~ for not and => for implies, or(v) and and(^) 
(P v Q)
CLIPS> (facts)
f-1     (sentence (sent "(" P "v" Q ")"))
f-2     (sentence (sent "(" "~" P "=>" Q ")"))
```

but i would like my output to read (sentence (sent "(~P=>Q)")) or something similar thx everyone

Answer (score 0):

Converting back to the original sentence with implode$ requires both creating a single multifield-value and transforming strings back to symbols. The **apply** function in the following code will do that:

```
         CLIPS (6.31 2/3/18)
CLIPS> 
(deffunction apply (?func $?list)
   (bind ?rv (create$))
   (foreach ?l ?list
      (bind ?rv (create$ ?rv (funcall ?func ?l))))
   ?rv)
CLIPS> 
(deftemplate sentence (multislot sent))
CLIPS> 
(defrule read-from-user
   =>
   (printout t "Please enter a sentence: Use ~ for not and => for implies, or(v) and and(^) please " crlf)
   (bind ?response (explode$ (readline)))
   (bind ?response (replace-member$ ?response "(" (sym-cat "(")))
   (bind ?response (replace-member$ ?response ")" (sym-cat ")")))
   (bind ?response (replace-member$ ?response "~" (sym-cat "~")))
   (bind ?response (replace-member$ ?response "v" (sym-cat "v")))
   (bind ?response (replace-member$ ?response "=>" (sym-cat "=>")))
   (bind ?response (replace-member$ ?response "^" (sym-cat "^")))
   (bind ?response (replace-member$ ?response "v" (sym-cat "v")))
   (assert (sentence (sent ?response))))
CLIPS> 
(defrule or-to-implies
   (sentence (sent $?before "(" ?symbolone "v" ?symboltwo ")" $?after))
    =>
   (assert 
      (sentence 
         (sent (implode$ 
                  (apply sym-cat $?before 
                                 "(" "~" ?symbolone "=>" ?symboltwo ")" 
                                 $?after))))))
CLIPS> (run)
Please enter a sentence: Use ~ for not and => for implies, or(v) and and(^) please 
(P v Q)
CLIPS> (facts)
f-0     (initial-fact)
f-1     (sentence (sent "(" P "v" Q ")"))
f-2     (sentence (sent "( ~ P => Q )"))
For a total of 3 facts.
CLIPS> (reset)
CLIPS> (run)
Please enter a sentence: Use ~ for not and => for implies, or(v) and and(^) please 
M ^ (P v Q) ^ R
CLIPS> (facts)
f-0     (initial-fact)
f-1     (sentence (sent M "^" "(" P "v" Q ")" "^" R))
f-2     (sentence (sent "M ^ ( ~ P => Q ) ^ R"))
For a total of 3 facts.
CLIPS>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I appreciate the help a lot.